# GoLang Mongo GeoJSON

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, geojson

In Golang, with MongoDB, I am trying to store GeoJSON objects, while keeping a 2dsphere index.

I am unable to declare a generic struct that can handle both "Point" and "Polygon", since a "Point" have a `[]float64` coordinates field, while a "Polygon" have a `[][]float64` coordinates field.

Do you have any idea on how to declare such a struct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using `interface` as field for both `polygon` and `point` in your struct. I created a simple program for your scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type figure struct {
    name        string
    coordinates interface{}
}

func main() {

    Point := figure{"Point", [2]float64{2.0, 7.88}}
    Polygon := figure{"Polygon", [2][2]float64{{2.0, 7.88}, {3.0, 7.88}}}
    fmt.Println(Point)
    fmt.Println(Polygon)

}
```

Output:

```
{Point [2 7.88]}
{Polygon [[2 7.88] [3 7.88]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [Ghoper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15987147/gopher)'s answer is **100%** correct. The inclusion of `Coordinates interface{}` helped me massively. For anyone who visits here in the future this is my GeoJson Feature Collection struct layout for refernce:

```golang
// Feature Collection
type FeatureCollection struct {
    ID       string    `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Features []Feature `json:"features" bson:"features"`
    Type     string    `json:"type" bson:"type"`
}

// Individual Feature
type Feature struct {
    Type       string     `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Properties Properties `json:"properties" bson:"properties"`
    Geometry   Geometry   `json:"geometry" bson:"geometry"`
}

// Feature Properties
type Properties struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Height      uint64 `json:"height" bson:"height"`
    Purchased   bool   `json:"purchased" bson:"purchased"`
    LastUpdated string `json:"last_updated" bson:"last_updated"`
}

// Feature Geometry
type Geometry struct {
    Type        string      `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Coordinates interface{} `json:"coordinates" bson:"coordinates"`
}
```

Works for *all* GeoJson Types ( LineString, Point, Polygon, MultiPolygon )